# Attempting to copy MyClass(QObject) throws a RuntimeError in Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on **PyQt5** application and trying to understand why I can't use `copy.copy` on a class which is inherited from `QObject`
Here is the header of my `Switcher` class:

```
class Switcher(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.modified = True
        self.integer_sliders = []
        self.float_sliders = []
        self.checkboxes = []
        self.drop_downs = []
(...)
```

I need to create two copies of `Switcher` class and in order to do so I use `copy`:

```
switch = Switcher()
new_switch = copy.copy(switch)
```

However this throws a `RuntimeError`:

```
RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type Switcher was never called
```

Why is this happening and is it possible to copy a `Switcher` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that `copy` could do is create a shallow copy of the *python wrapper* for the C++ object. This is because it is a python function, and so knows nothing about the Qt object that underlies the wrapper.

But even if it *did* know about the underlying object, there would still be no way to copy it, because Qt does not provide a copy constructor for `QObject`. So what you are asking for simply makes no sense.

Anyway, I would guess that you don't actually need to copy the `QObject` itself. What you really need to do is copy certain *data attributes* of it - and for that, you can easily write your own method.